# How to give names in PieChart each slice Coreplot iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, slice, pie-chart

I draw PieChart with 4 slices in iPhone app. I want to add Names in each Slice in Pie Chart. Am using Core-Plot9. And also i want to give different colors for each slice in PieChart. How can do this? Please suggest me any idea/sample code to do this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the samples from given link then go to
 CorePlot_0.9->Source->examples->CPTTestApp-iPhone check this sample. it will give you an idea how to solve your problem?
    [core plot example](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=CorePlot_0.9.zip&can=2&q=)